# Shortening a question

Tags: questions

There is a game when two players call words in turn. A prompt in the game (written as a computer program) can look like

```
Plyer1, what is your word?
```

Can it be shortened the following way

```
Player1, your word?
```

Comment: Even "Player1?" should do.

Comment: @Kris Thanks. I decided to output like "Player 1, your word?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be understood that way well enough. Alternatives:

- Just "Player1" (will it be the name of the person, or will it always be Player1? if the later you may consider to put a space: "Player 1").
- "Player1, you say:" (notice the colon)
- "Player1's word:"

Comment: I want to use just "Player1" and "Player2".

Comment: Or maybe indeed it is better to write "Player 1" and "Player 2"... Do I need to place a comma after "Player 1" before "your word?"?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I would put the comma. You would use the phrase while playing cards with your pals and then, in English, you would make a small pause: "Andrei, your card!".

Comment: `Player1, your turn:` would be the expected prompt